# sorting BAM file error using samtools

Tags: rna-seq, sam, samtools

I have few bam files and would like to get read counts using

```
samtools idxstats
```

[Data is aligned to hg19 transcriptome]. To use that command I need a sorted bam file. So to sort them I gave the following command.

```
samtools sort -T /tmp/input.sorted -o input.sorted.bam input.bam
```

This ended up showing:

```
[W::bam_hdr_read] EOF marker is absent. The input is probably truncated.
[E::bgzf_read] bgzf_read_block error -1 after 0 of 4 bytes
[bam_sort_core] truncated file. Aborting.
```

And the tmp dir has 6 input.sorted.nnnn.bam files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause of the error is that your input file is truncated or /tmp is running out of space. If you can do `samtools view -H input.bam` without error (reading the header also checks for the magic number at the end of the file) then it's like the that /tmp is filling up.

Comment: I did "samtools view -H input.bam" there is no error. It ended up showing all the header things which I asked here [https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/3080/read-counts-from-bam-file/3081?noredirect=1#comment4889_3081]

Comment: Then either /tmp is full or otherwise one of the files there is somehow corrupt (you can test them with `samtools view -H` too).

Comment: Ok. looks like that file is corrupt. And I tried with other bam file and showed - [bam_sort_core] merging from 24 files... and I see a sorted.bam file. I used "samtools idxstats sorted.bam" - This is what I see - [bam_idxstats] fail to load the index.

Comment: Don't forget to `samtools index sorted.bam`

Comment: Ok. So, after the indexing I used idxstats and it showed 4 columns without any headers.                                                                                                        NR_039978 984 38 0
NM_130786 1766 1 0
NM_138932 9293 37 0
NM_033110 2678 2 0
NM_000014 4678 4 0
NM_144670 5192 18 0
NR_040112 1201 2 0
NM_017436 2106 76 0
NM_016161 1771 0 0

Comment: They are (in order): contig name, contig length, number of mapped reads, number of unmapped reads (this will typically be 0).

Comment: Ok. Thankyou. So, for DE analysis what I need is mapped reads. how do I get the gene names? Can I use edgeR for DE analysis using the mapped reads?

Comment: You mapped to the transcriptome, so they're the first column.

Comment: Yes, I see that. Is there any way to get the gene id/ transcript id from this results. And may I know the answer for DE analysis edgeR?

Comment: If you want to get annotation (like gene symbols) coupled to your accession numbers, please read the [biomaRt](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/biomaRt/inst/doc/biomaRt.html) user guide. If you have questions after reading it, please start a new question in stead of discussing it in the comments.